# Trying to use mocha, ES6 modules, and ts-node with the --experimental-loader option

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, es6-modules, ts-node

I'm trying to get the ts-node option `--experimental-loader` working along with mocha, and having no luck. Until I started trying to compile ES6 modules, I used to be able to run mocha tests this way:

```
"test": "nyc --reporter=html mocha --require ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts"
```

That doesn't work anymore when generating ES6 modules.

I'd use the `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\" }'` solution for testing, but that won't work for me because of another complication: I'm generating ES6 modules as a first step in my build, but *also* generating ES5/CommonJS modules using webpack and babel. That last step doesn't work unless I add `.js` to the end of my local TypeScript `import` statements.

But adding those `.js` extensions turns out to break the `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\" }'` solution, which will work, however, if I go back and delete all of the `.js` extensions. I obviously don't want a test and build process where I have to keep going back and forth between adding and removing those extensions.

To simplify for now, I've taken out nyc, and I'm trying to run tests like this:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register --experimental-loader ./ts-loader.mjs src/**/*.spec.ts
```

I get no errors this way, but nothing happens either. It's like the `src/**/*.spec.ts` doesn't exist.

My do-nothing (for now) dummy loader looks like this:

```
console.log('ts-loader loaded');

export async function resolve(specifier, context, defaultResolve) {
  console.log('resolve');
  return defaultResolve(specifier, context, defaultResolve);
}

export async function getFormat(url, context, defaultGetFormat) {
  console.log('getFormat');
  return defaultGetFormat(url, context, defaultGetFormat);
}

export async function getSource(url, context, defaultGetSource) {
  console.log('getSource');
  return defaultGetSource(url, context, defaultGetSource);
}

export async function transformSource(source, context, defaultTransformSource) {
  console.log('transformSource');
  return defaultTransformSource(source, context, defaultTransformSource);
}

export function getGlobalPreloadCode() {
  console.log('getGlobalPreloadCode');
  return '';
}
```

I can tell it gets loaded because the `'ts-loader loaded'` message appears, but none of the functions ever get called.

I've tried other permutations, but just get errors like `src/**/*.spec.ts` being treated as a literal file name instead of a glob, or errors about modules not being found.

I was hoping to see my loader invoked for every `import` being handled, and then figuring out how to manipulate the file extensions, but I haven't managed to get that far yet. Any suggestions?

I'm using node v14.15.1. The full code for my project, with a working build, but broken tests, can be found here: https://github.com/kshetline/tubular_math

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, although it wasn't along the lines I was originally looking for. I gave up on trying to make mocha happy with the extra `.js` extensions, and found a way to make webpack happy without them. So...

```
import { Angle, Mode, Unit } from './angle.js';
```

...went back to...

```
import { Angle, Mode, Unit } from './angle';
```

My test script looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && tsc && webpack && webpack --env target=umd",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.ts'",
    "test": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\":\"commonjs\"}' nyc --reporter=html mocha --require ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts"
  },
```

And finally, most importantly, I figured out how to make webpack 5.x (4.x didn't have this issue) happy with local JavaScript imports that don't have a `.js` extension, which webpack now otherwise insists upon if your `package.json` says `"type": "module"`:

```
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader', resolve: { fullySpecified: false } }
      ]
    }
```

...where setting `fullySpecified` to false is the key to the solution.

**UPDATE**: The above example was done working on a deliberately simple project, something easy for a starter to generate an npm package with ESM modules. Now that I'm trying something a little more advanced, I've run into a snag again running unit tests. As soon as a *.spec.ts file directly or indirectly imports external code, module loading fails. I can only test code with no external dependencies until I figure out how to fix that problem. Apparently using `"TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\":\"commonjs\"}'` is only letting me go one level deep into fixing the basic problem with running mocha along with ts-node.

Comment: Having exact same problem with unit tests. Have a UMD that Webpack happily imports via `import * as umd from "umd";`, but mocha gets an error from the same code. Randomly got it to work somehow, but then I rebuilt, and everything fails again. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. In fact I recently wanted to use an ESM-only npm package (double-metaphone) in a TypeScript project. I got so frustrated with the various module format issues that I gave up and copied the source code (fortunately small) directly into my project rather than importing the package.

Comment: I ended up doing what I was specifically trying to avoid: bundling my specs along with source via webpack and running tests with a browser via Karma. Seems like a very heavy package just to be able to run some tests that aren't being integrated with other modules. However, the module resolution just doesn't work when importing a non-es6 module in mocha.