# How to make es6 module imports resolve correctly both for compiling via tsc and executing unit tests with Mocha without compiling using ts-node

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, es6-modules, ts-node

I have an npm based project using typescript and es6 module imports.

To execute unit testing without having to compile the typescript, Mocha with ts-node is used.

For the typescript to compile correctly, the `.js` file extension needs to be included in the import statements in the source code. So:

```js
import module from "./module"
// Results in runtime error, can't find module

import module from "./module.js";
// executes correctly during runtime
```

However, when running unit tests via a script that calls Mocha combined with `ts-node/register`, the file extensions need to be omitted in the source code import statements:

```js
import module from "./module.js"
// error thrown, can't find module

import module from "./module";
// unit test executes correctly
```

I'm fairly certain it's an issue with how `ts-node` resolves the module imports vs how `tsc` does it, but am not certain on how to work around/solve the issue without compiling the source code first which I want to avoid if possible.

My `package.json` contains (with some properties omitted to make it a bit less verbose):

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./npm-fs.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "env TS_NODE_PROJECT='src/test/ts/tsconfig.json' mocha -r ts-node/register --extension ts --recursive true src/test/ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.14",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.9",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "typedoc": "^0.19.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

The `tsconfig.json` for my unit tests are:

```json
{
  "include": ["./**/*.ts", "../../main/ts/**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "target": "ES2020"
  }
}
```

Switching the `module` property from `commonjs` to `es2020` results in `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` to be thrown instead of being unable to find the imported modules.

I've tried researching and looking up similar issues to find solutions and the answers I've found haven't worked or are for a different environment (i.e. not using ts-node).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution: [Trying to use mocha, ES6 modules, and ts-node with the --experimental-loader option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376414/trying-to-use-mocha-es6-modules-and-ts-node-with-the-experimental-loader-opt)

This might help you if determined to do it this way:
You might find an answer here: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007

Sounds like for node

```
node --loader ts-node/esm --es-module-specifier-resolution=node ./my-script.ts
```

can work. What about

```
mocha --loader ts-node/esm --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --extension ts --recursive true src/test/ts
```

for mocha? Total guess, untested

This post seems to agree, if I read it right. https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4274